# How can I show an element that has display: none in a CSS rule?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a really simple external css stylesheet that has the following :

```
div.hideBox {
    display:none;
}
```

So when the html page loads, the div with that class attribute 'hideBox' will not show on the page, which is what I want. But I the box to show/appear when a user clicks on a button on that same page. I tried to use the onclick event to do this, but the div won't show.

So for example, the code would be :

```
<script language="javascript">
function showmydiv() {
document.getElementById('mybox').style.display = "";
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mybox" class="hideBox">
some output of text
</div>
<input type="button" name="ShowBox" value="Show Box" onclick="showmydiv()">
```

What's strange is that a setup similar to this works when I use `visibility:hidden; position:absolute;` and I can use a JavaScript function to show the `<div>`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers?

Comment: Yes, I tested in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Because setting the `div`'s `display` style property to `""` doesn't change anything in the CSS rule itself. That basically just creates an "empty," **inline** CSS rule, which has no effect beyond clearing the same property on that element.

You need to set it to something that *has* a value:

```
document.getElementById('mybox').style.display = "block";
```

What you're doing *would* work if you were replacing an **inline** style on the div, like this:

```
<div id="myBox" style="display: none;"></div>

document.getElementById('mybox').style.display = "";
```

Comment: I believe what happens when you set display to "" is that it returns to the original display value (that was set in the css).

Comment: @Juan: when you set an inline `display` style to `""` it simply removes the inline style.

Comment: What if I do not want it do be displayed as block? I just need the default (empty) value to override one that came from the class.

Comment: @Paul - The default value is not empty but 'inline' or 'block', depending on the element.

Answer (score 13):

```
document.getElementById('mybox').style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 6):

try setting the display to block in your javascript instead of a blank value.

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you want to write you own short javascript for this, but have you considered to use Frameworks for HTML manipulation instead? jQuery is my prefered tool for such a task, eventhough its an overkill for your current question as it has SO many extra functionalities.

[Have a look at jQuery here](http://jquery.com)